# removing a point from a unit circle results in a connected space

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

This is an example our TA gave us.
"If we removed a finite numbers of points of the unit circle the resulting set is connected"
Can somebody explain why??

Comment: Nobody can, because it is false!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Really?! I might misunderstood what they said. Why is it false?

Comment: If you remove one point it remains connected. But if you remove more than one point it becomes disconnected.

Comment: If you consider the circle $S^1$ it is connected but if you consider $S^1-\{p,q\}$, with $p\ne q$, then you can write $S^1-\{p,q\}$ as the disjoint union of two connected components.

Comment: By the unit circle, do you mean $S^1$ or $D^2$? I.e. the the boundary of the closed ball of radius one and center zero, or the ball itself?

Answer (score 1):

Proof of the fact that the unit circle $S^{1}$ remains connected after removing one point from it: If $e^{i\theta}$ is removed from the circle then define $f: (0,1) \to S^{1}\setminus \{e^{i\theta}\}$ by $f(t)=e^{2\pi it +i\theta}$. Then $f$ is a homeomorhism . Since $(0,1)$ is connected so is the image $S^{1}\setminus \{e^{i\theta}\}$.